# csv content filtering by list elments in Python

Tags: python, csv, filter

I got stuck in getting the right result from a simple piece of Python code ( I am a Python beginner anyway).
Given a csv input file (ListInput.csv):
pKT, pET, pUT,

and another csv file which contains features of many of these elements (Table.csv):

```
pBR,156,AATGGT,673,HHHTTTT,
pUT,54,CCATGTACCTAT,187,PRPTP,
pHTM,164,GGTATAG,971,WYT,
pKT,12,GCATACAGGAC,349,,
pET,87,GTGACGGTA,506,PPMK,
```

............ and so on

I aim to get a selection based on the first csv file elements in order to get a csv file as output (WorkingList.txt), in this case the expected result would be:

```
pKT,12,GCATACAGGAC,349,,
pET,87,GTGACGGTA,506,PPMK,
pUT,54,CCATGTACCTAT,187,PRPTP,
```

I wrote the following script which does not gives errors but end up with an empty file as output. I am tryng to understand why since a couple of days with no success. Any help is gratly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

v = open('ListInput.csv', 'rt')
csv_v = csv.reader(v)

vt = open('Table.csv', 'rt')
csv_vt = csv.reader(vt)

with open("WorkingList.txt", "a+t") as myfile:
    pass


for el in csv_v:
    for var in csv_vt:
        if el == var[0]:
            myfile.write(var)

myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

**First problem:**

You consume your input csv iterator `csv_vt` at the first iteration. You need to do:

```
vt.seek(0)
```

to rewind the file for the inner loop. This leave a `O(n^2)` search algorithm but at least it works.

**Second problem:**

you're opening & closing `my_file` in the `with` block. When you reach your `for` loop, `my_file` is already closed because you went out of the `with` block (that's the guarantee of the `with` block).

Hadn't you have the first problem you'd had cross paths with "operation on closed file" when trying to write the output.

I'd rewrite the last part within the `with` block and remove the `close()`.

**Third problem**

you cannot write a list to a file, you have to create a `csv.writer` object first.

So to sum it up, you could solve all problems plus the performance problem with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

v = open('ListInput.csv', 'rt')
csv_v = csv.reader(v)

with open('Table.csv', 'rt') as vt:
    csv_vt = csv.reader(vt)
    # create a dictionary to speed up lookup
    # read the table only once
    vdict = {var[0]:var for var in csv_vt}

with open("WorkingList.txt", newline="") as myfile:  # for Python 3.x
## with open("WorkingList.txt", "wb") as myfile:  # for Python 2
    cw = csv.writer(myfile)
    for el in csv_v:
        if el[0] in vdict:
            cw.writerow(vdict[el])

v.close()
```

`vdict` is the lookup table which replaces your inner loop (only works if the "keys" are unique, which seem to be the case given your input samples)

Comment: This code does not work. I really appreciated your efforts to help. Now, I  will try to find a different successfull approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Here is the piece of code that works:

```
import csv

with open('ListInput.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    vinput = []
    flist = []
    for row in readCSV:
        vi = row
        vinput.append(vi)

        print(vinput)

with open('Table.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    readTable = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    vtable = []
    for row in readTable:
        vt = row
        for rig in vi:
            el = rig
            if str(el) in vt:
                vtable.append(vt)


    print(vtable)        

with open (r'WorkingTable.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_file:
    write=csv.writer(write_file)
    write.writerows([r] for r in vtable)
```